# C++ boost::thread, how to start a thread inside a class

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost

How can I start a thread inside an object? For example,

```
class ABC
{
public:
void Start();
double x;
boost::thread m_thread;
};

ABC abc;
... do something here ...
... how can I start the thread with Start() function?, ...
... e.g., abc.m_thread = boost::thread(&abc.Start()); ...
```

So that later I can do something like,

```
abc.thread.interrupt();
abc.thread.join();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use boost.bind:

```
boost::thread(boost::bind(&ABC::Start, abc));
```

You probably want a pointer (or a shared_ptr):

```
boost::thread* m_thread;
m_thread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&ABC::Start, abc));
```

Answer (score 21):

You need neither bind, nor pointer.

```
boost::thread m_thread;
//...
m_thread = boost::thread(&ABC::Start, abc);
```

Comment: +1: You're right.  There is a constructor with arguments that is equivalent to using bind.  I prefer bind as I find it more readable.  There's also support for moving the thread, I guess I like the pointer because I know what's going on (copy vs. move) though hopefully everything is going towards move...